# HTML - setting up a custom domain when using links like: href="/something"

Tags: html

I've been looking for a way to force browsers to add my custom address when using links without full domain. Lets say i have a link:
[link](/link)  (please see source, i didnt specify domain)
Is there any way to tell browser that my link should lead to stackoverflow.com/en/link instead of stackoverflow.com/link? Ty in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about htaccess? If you don't know what it means, google it.

Comment: Do you mean something like the base HTML tag?

Comment: Or something like the MVC framework?

Comment: @Ranveer no, I dont talk about htaccess. Read my question again. See source of my link (href="/link") see? No domain specified, i would like it to point to stackoverflow.com/en/link, but i cant use htaccess as i have something else at stackoverflow.com/link. Kinda messy but you should get it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question correctly.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly ye something like base tag but it wont work for my problem. Base tag is only for relative urls and this is not the case :(

Comment: I am not aware of any other solutions that works on the client side (browser). Maybe JavaScript? What is the puspose of this? Maybe there is a different approach.

Comment: I've developed custom multisite cms, client wants another site but he doesnt want subdomain but just /en url after current one, lol. Nevermind then, ill just change the way links are created then. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, use the `<base>` tag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/en/">
```

Comment: Maybe also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag

Comment: It would work if i used href="link", but not for "/link". Thats my problem